# How can I add the suggestion button in my Chatbot?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I am creating a chatbot by Flutter and DialogFlow. Now I want to add some suggestion button into the chat screen right after saying "Hello" like this:
suggestion buttons sample

[image]

I am a Flutter newbie so I need some ideas to create these buttons. Do you have any idea about this? Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution!

(Don't forget to replace `YOUR_INTENT_NAME` with the correct value.)

```js
QueryResult result = await DialogflowApi.detectIntent(query, languageCode);
if (result.intent.displayName == 'YOUR_INTENT_NAME') {
  return Column(
    children: [
      Text(result.fulfillmentText),
      SizedBox(height: 10),
      Wrap(
        spacing: 8.0,
        runSpacing: 4.0,
        children: List<Widget>.generate(
          result.fulfillmentMessages[0].suggestions.suggestions.length,
          (index) => SuggestionChip(
            label: Text(result.fulfillmentMessages[0].suggestions.suggestions[index]),
            onPressed: () => _handleSuggestionTap(result.fulfillmentMessages[0].suggestions.suggestions[index]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```